# ConstraintLayout constraints attribute in style

Tags: android

How to use constraint attributes in style?

When I'm trying to use it as any other attributes with custom namespace it's has no effect on my view.

```html
 <style name="Header.Center" parent="Header">
    <item name="layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf">parent</item>
 </style>
```

Adding namespace **app:** is not helping.

Comment: I've tried it and id kind of worked. However, within your layout xml, while it does align the view correctly, it will still show the warning that you have to "add constraints or the view will be put in the top left corner at runtime".
I would advise against doing this at all until android studio correctly supports this.

Comment: Also you can add tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" to the parent constraint layout if you ensure that constraints is working correctly.

Answer (score 15):

First of all, make sure that the `View` that you're applying the style on is a direct child of the `ConstraintLayout`. Otherwise, the constraints will not be taken into account when positioning the `View`.

I have tried it and the way you tried does in fact work. I have added the following style to the `styles.xml`:

```
<style name="CustomStyle">
    <item name="layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf">parent</item>
    <item name="layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf">parent</item>
</style>
```

Created a basic layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:text="Text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/CustomStyle"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And it does indeed position the `TextView` at the bottom right corner of the parent.

Comment: for me actually deleting *app:* made it work; leaving it makes layout behave weirdly

Answer (score 2):

maybe your view's attribute is "match_parent",but it is wrong.
It should be "wrap_content".

```
 <TextView
            android:text="Text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/CustomStyle"/>
```