# Styles for Children of ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-styles, android-constraintlayout

I wanna set general style for my inner elements of my `ConstraintLayout`. For example, I have multiple `TextView`s with following attributes:

```
    <TextView
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
      android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
      app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>
```

I created this style for it:

```
    <style name="PageTitleStyle">
      <item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>
      <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
      <item name="android:layout_marginRight">8dp</item>
      <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">8dp</item>
   </style>
```

but how can I set these attributes to the defined style?

```
       app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51049653/constraintlayout-constraints-attribute-in-style

Comment: have you tried adding it like this in your style ?
`<item name="app:app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf">parent</item>`

Comment: @MuzammilHusnain It can't be built.

Comment: yes it is showing error

Answer (score 3):

You can define your attributes in styles as follows:

```
<style name="MyStyle">
    <item name="layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf">parent</item>
    <item name="layout_constraintRight_toRightOf">parent</item>
</style>
```

You can then specify `style="@style/MyStyle"` on each `TextView`.

Setting the style on the `ConstraintLayout` will not set the style on the children of the `ConstraintLayout` unless you set the style as a theme. See ["Apply a style as a theme"](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes#Theme). (Emphasis is mine.)

> Beginning with Android 5.0 (API level 21) and Android Support Library v22.1, you can also specify the android:theme attribute to a view in your layout file. This modifies the theme for that view **and any child views**, which is useful for altering theme color palettes in a specific portion of your interface.

So you would add `android:theme="@style/MyStyle"` to the `ConstraintLayout`. This will replace the existing theme, so you may want to set your `AppTheme` as the parent of `MyStyle`.

There is one odd-looking side effect that I have noticed in doing this: The constraints named in the style effect the display of the layout in the studio designer (correctly) but the constraints themselves do not display. The layout editor will also not pick up that the constraints are defined in the style and will give "constraint missing" errors. (Android Studio 3.3 RC3)

Answer (score 0):

Relation constraints can not be used in "style". Try to use it in layout